# Programmatically register stripe webhooks

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I have an application that fetches stripe charge data periodically and creates a correlation with data from our system. Currently we are batching requests to stripe's api with our clients API key.

This works great but its not true real-time and its killing our servers with wasteful API calls.

Is there a way to register a webhook on our stripe account that will listen for events that happen on other api keys so that we can provide a more real-time experience to our customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using your clients' API keys, you should set up your account as a [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) platform, and have your clients connect their account to yours.

Once this is done, you will be able to issue API requests on behalf on your clients, by using your own API key and the [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) header.

You will also be able to set up a Connect [webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) that will let you receive all events from accounts that are connected to yours. These events will include a [`user_id`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#webhooks) field with the [`id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object-id) of the account that sent the event.